# remote desktop view of a Debian Lenny Machine

Tags: debian, remote, remote-management

Let me give a summary of my project specification. I have a windows server and bunch of debian clients on the same LAN, Debian machines do not have x window system, they are bound to command line use. I am running a QT application on system start so user only interacts with my GUI before he sees anything else.

According to my project requirements, we should allow system admins to view what end user is doing in debian machines at any time, therefore he should be able to see their screens at any time. He will be using a windows machine to do that. Therefore I am wondering if it is possible to share debian's screen with a windows server, and what would be involved in that.

Do I need  VNC server setup on debian machines to accomplish that? Is there any other way?

Comment: Does the QT app only run on the console?

Comment: yes it is being run from the console since there is no GUI.

Comment: The normal way to share an existing X session through VNC is with something like `x11vnc`.  However, if you're not using X, and are instead running Qt embedded directly on the Linux framebuffer, `x11vnc` won't help you.  I don't think there are any existing tools that will share a Linux framebuffer via VNC.  Qt can be compiled with VNC server support, but as far as I understand this would replace your existing framebuffer display, rather than working simultaneously.

Comment: that's a bummer, I hope I can find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you only have terminal usage on the client side (you said that you have no kind of xserver running on the client hosts) I have a suggestion how you can achieve this. It's actually a minimal but easily expandable example that shows how you can monitor a terminal session on a remote host. I don't know any special software for that and probably there are a number of ways to achieve this more elegant, so please do not expect to much.

My first advice is to install `rootsh` on the client side.

> It's a wrapper for shells which logs all echoed keystrokes and
>   terminal output to a file and/or to syslog [[rootsh website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/)]

Unfortunately your debian repository is not packed with it, so you have to make your own binaries. Which is easy to achieve since rootsh has no fancy dependencies. Further more you need `socat`, a tool for bidirectional data transfer.

If you invoke `rootsh` like

```
./rootsh -i -f logfile
```

a new login shell starts an everything echoed on the terminal from this shell or any child process is written into `logfile` (also special characters originally intended for the tty).

Now you can create a TCP-socket on the client with

```
socat OPEN:logfile,ioreeof TCP-LISTEN:22222,fork
```

from which you can read from the admin's host. For instance with

```
 socat TCP:clientdomain:22222 STDOUT
```

or with `netcat` i.e. `telnet` (windows binaries for socat are available).

In the case you want to have a more secure data stream between the nodes you can also instruct `socat` to encrypt it via `OPENSSL`. You can find a great explanation on this in the article *[Securing Traffic Between two Socat Instances Using SSL](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html)*.

I admit that my approach has several flaws, but it suffices to illustrate what's possible without any special tools.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, I will give it a try whenever I have chance and will let you know.

Comment: One question though, I don't think that I will be able to monitor my program's GUI with your method, even though debian does not have x window system, when my program launches from command line, it launches its own GUI. So you interact with a GUI, Will I be able to view users actions on this GUI?

Comment: if it's a textbased gui it's no problem since all terminal characters are transmitted. It is textbased, isn't it :)

Comment: unfortunately it's not a text based GUI:) I guess there's no easy way of solving this problem

Comment: So Qt could access your video-cards framebuffer directly!? That would be crazy!

Comment: sorry maybe I am confused about what you meant by text based UI, our application's UI have images, forms, buttons etc, allows mouse interactions, I never thought that it would count as a text based UI.

Comment: that sounds like that your gui is run as a client of an running xserver. Maybe you look at your running processes and check if Xorg or sth. is running.

Comment: I will check that first thing tomorrow morning.Thanks again

Comment: I don't see xorg in the processes list, looks like we've been using QT embedded in linux framebuffer.

Comment: In fact it seems that Qt-embedded is meant to run without a x-server. I didn't know that anything like this is feasible by one of the popular guis. On [qt-embedded-install](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt-embedded-install.html) i found a [link](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt-embedded-vnc.html) where it is described how you can work with vnc. So it should be possible to make it.

Comment: thanks so much, yes it looks like if it is feasible if I build qt with the appropriate flags.